# DDR3 SODIMM slow clock specification

Tags: memory, ram, ddr3

I am considering to design memory controller handling 1GB of the RAM. I did already design controller for Micron's 32MB SDRAM in the past using Cyclone III device.

The new design is for retro computing, and there will be no need in high speed access, let's say access cycle would be ok at 100 ns. The main property is the size of the RAM, and it is a reason I am thinking about SODIMM (mobile computer memory module), which is socketed and easily replaceable.

The controller might be an FPGA (however I see DDR2 controller available in the MegaWizard), or anything else with preferably available building blocks.

The main issue I currently face is identification of the minimal clock frequency for the module. Chips' datasheets seem to have this information (e.g. [MT41K1G8](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/dram/ddr3/8gb_ddr3l.pdf), page 73. table 54 - clock cycle is up to 3.9 us), but this information is not available for SO-DIMM modules (e.g. [MT8KTF12864HZ](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/modules/sodimm/ktf8c128_256_512x64hz.pdf)) listing only "typical" 1.5 ns timing.

There's another document called [DDR3 Point-to-Point Design Support](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/dram/tn4113_ddr3_point_to_point_design.pdf) listing at page 3 table 1 "slow clock debug" advantage of DDR3, with lowest clock to be 12.5 MHz (80 ns), but again, this document is for DDR3 chip rather than memory module.

Is there any body of knowledge which would help me to identify how can I apply DDR3 module for slow access in more or less cost-effective manner, or I am looking in wrong direction and there's even better way to put a GB into the retro computer?

Comment: you might want to mention what kind of memory bus you're planning to attach that memory to.

Comment: The controller connects to Z80-based system, 8 bits data bus width. All the data and address translations will be performed in the controller.

Comment: um, OK.... um... how does a Z80 address 1 GB of RAM? It doesn't have even remotely that address space size.

Comment: This is another topic, active 16K bank is selectable through I/O regisetrs, and this design is already available (nothing to invent here :)

Comment: yeah, but banked access makes a bit of a design goal, right? I'm a bit relentless here, but: do you have provisions to have 2¹⁶ different 16K banks? That sounds like a lot.

Comment: anyway, why is the DDR clock a problem for you? It's not like that would have anything to do with your Z80's memory bus clock: The FPGA (or whatever) would interface with the DDR at high speed, and interface with the Z80 at low speed. It's an asynchronous bus, anyway!

Comment: All DDR variants have a minimum clock rate for proper operation. The slow clock debug mode requires the internal DLL to be *disabled* and I am not sure of how that would impact the controller (you would need to consult the FPGA documents).

Comment: @MarcusMüller it may be an issue for the following reasons: board layout (lower speed=relaxed layout), FPGA speed grade (e.g. Quartus says warning grade 8 does not support [even] DDR2 controller, grade 6 only supports on specific pins, but there's no much sense to pay double for grade 6 FPGA). I am ok to develop my own controller if it will be proven that DDR3 module will work properly/compatible with lower clock speeds, e.g. 40 MHz.

Comment: I honestly doubt that will fly in the long term – at a reasonable DDR clock rate, you will need to do strict design for a 64 bit wide bus.

Comment: @MarcusMüller not sure I understand. Controller will work with DDR3 at one end, and with Z80 at another. The point is that I can not identify how slow it can work at DDR3 side to be withint specifications and be interoperable between SODIMM modules of various manufacturers.

Comment: @Anonymous and I'd argue that the problem you're trying to solve – avoiding the need for high-speed board design – won't be solved by running DDR3 at the lowest rate it supports.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Board layout was not said to be the problem. It is one of the factors of course, but not a problem.

Comment: You literally said "t may be an issue for the following reasons: board layout"...

Comment: Exactly, "may be". Thank you, I will pay special attention to layout even in lower clock environment (if it will come to designing after researching). And I still need material insight into the question I asked at the very top...